# Huge Graph Structure

Tags: python, memory, data-structures, graph

I'm developing an application in which I need a structure to represent a huge graph (between 1000000 and 6000000 nodes and 100 or 600 edges per node) in memory. The edges representation will contain some attributes of the relation.

I have tried a memory map representation, arrays, dictionaries and strings to represent that structure in memory, but these always crash because of the memory limit.

I would like to get an advice of how I can represent this, or something similar.

By the way, I'm using python.

Comment: you said there's only 600 edges - why not just store those?

Comment: Do you mean 100-600 edges per node?

Comment: You need to use a database, as your dataset, even with one pointer per piece of data, is enormous, let alone as python objects.  How you want to query and traverse your graph will determine what kind of database you use.

Comment: How much RAM is on your system?

Answer (score 14):

1. If that is 100-600 edges/node, then you are talking about 3.6 billion edges.
2. Why does this have to be all in memory?
3. Can you show us the structures you are currently using?
4. How much memory are we allowed (what is the memory limit you are hitting?)

If the only reason you need this in memory is because you need to be able to read and write it fast, then use a database.  Databases read and write extremely fast, often they can read without going to disk at all.

Comment: +1: this isnt an answer, but all these questions have to be answered before we can proceed

Comment: ok... each node has between 100 and 600 edges.
I have to keep this in memory (ram) because it has to be constantly accessed . Also it's going to be updated constantly, changing the weights of the relations, adding and removing nodes and edges.

All this thing must have a good performance (response time).

Comment: I have tried many differents structures like dictionaries, lists, and object combinations for representing the adjacency matrix. I, also have tried to map this intro a file, using and xt4 partion, but when I have to write random, it takes a lot of time and expends a lot of memory because the block writing.

Right now I'm testing this in my own machine with 4 gb. When I go implement it, I will use a server with some memory (I hope less than 1 Tera).

Comment: Use a database if it's read/write performance you are worried about.

Comment: Yeah... but what kind or which database are you talking about?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on you hardware resources an all in memory for a graph this size is probably out of the question. Two possible options from a graph specific DB point of view are:

- [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) - claims to easily handle billions of nodes and its been in development a long time.
- [FlockDB](http://github.com/twitter/flockdb) - newly released by Twitter this is a distributed graph database.

Since your using Python, have you looked at [Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/)? How far did you get loading a graph of this size if you have looked at it out of interest?

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have tried networkx but it does fit my requirements (use a lot of memory). Neo4j is too expensive. I will tried with flockDB.

Comment: I have read about FlockDB... it looks pretty cool, but I have a lot of problems to install it. I think FlockDB is in alpha version. It doesn't have good documentation / support.

Comment: Neo4j does have an open-source version which may be useful. https://neo4j.com/open-source-project/

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you'll be able to use a memory structure unless you have a LOT of memory at your disposal:

Assume you are talking about 600 directed edges from each node, with a node being 4-bytes (integer key) and a directed edge being JUST the destination node keys (4 bytes each).

Then the raw data about each node is 4 + 600 * 4 = 2404 bytes x 6,000,000 = over 14.4GB

That's without any other overheads or any additional data in the nodes (or edges).

Comment: However, systems with 16GB or more of RAM are fairly common.  I've got a used HP server that I paid less than $500 for with 16 GB.  I have servers at work with 512 GB, or 1TB.  I've even used some at a previous job with multiple TB of RAM.  For instance, here's an old Dell that supports up to 6 TB: http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/productdetails/poweredge-r920

Comment: @BrianMinton the point is still valid now as it was 7 years ago.  Once you add on the allocation system to manage that amount of data, it's still very significant to store such a structure in memory instead of simply persisting it to an appropriate database structure.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have very few edges considering the amount of nodes - suggesting that most of the nodes aren't strictly necessary. So, instead of actually storing all of the nodes, why not use a sparse structure and only insert them when they're in use? This should be pretty easy to do with a dictionary; just don't insert the node until you use it for an edge.

The edges can be stored using an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) on the nodes.

Of course, this only applies if you really mean 100-600 nodes in total. If you mean per node, that's a completely different story.

Answer (score 3):

The [scipy.sparse.csgraph](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html) package may be able to handle this -- 5 million nodes * 100 edges on average is 500 million pairs, at 8 bytes per pair (two integer IDs) is just about 4GB. I think `csgraph` uses compression so it will use less memory than that; this could work on your laptop.

csgraph doesn't have as many features as networkx but it uses waaay less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 600 per node, you could try something like this:

```
import os.path
import cPickle
class LazyGraph:
    def __init__(self,folder):
        self.folder = folder

    def get_node(self,id):
        f = open(os.path.join(self.folder,str(id)),'rb')
        node = cPickle.load(f)
        f.close() # just being paranoid
        return node

    def set_node(self,id,node):
        f = open(os.path.join(self.folder,str(id)),'wb')
        cPickle.dump(node,f,-1) # use highest protocol
        f.close() # just being paranoid
```

Use arrays (or numpy arrays) to hold the actual node ids, as they are faster.

Note, this will be very very slow.

You could use threading to pre-fetch nodes (assuming you knew which order you were processing them in), but it won't be fun.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a database and an iterator over the results. Then you wouldn't have to keep it all in memory at the same time but you could always have access to it.

Comment: He certainly needs some kind of datastore that isn't memory, but what's "an iterator over the results"?  Graph algorithms generally aren't going to be satisfied with a simple iterator.

Comment: I might mean "generator", as in `(grape[stem] for grape in bunch)` or a function that uses `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide to use some kind of database after all, I suggest looking at [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) and its python bindings. It's a graph database capable of handling large graphs. Here's a [presentation](http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/schedule/event/115/) from this year's PyCon.